# Problem generating random simulation using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to run a simulation on because I'm pretty sure the gacha game I'm playing is coding their probability wrong.

In particular, the game can be explained as: from turn 1 to 99, there's a 0.5% chance of a successful pull; from turn 100 to 199, there's a 1% chance of a successful pull, and on turn 200, it's a guaranteed pull. Mathematically, the probability of getting a successful pull before turn 200 is 1 - 0.995 ^ 100 * 0.99 ^ 99, or around 78%.

I can do this correctly using for loops, but when I try to do this via pandas, it returns nearly 100% chance of a successful pull (which is wrong - should be around 78%). I'm wondering what's wrong with my simulation code.

```
num_simulations = 1000
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(199, num_simulations))
df.loc[:100, :] = df.loc[:100, :] <= 0.995
df.loc[100:, :] = df.loc[100:, :] <= 0.99
# if False, implies successful pull
Counter(df.loc[:, :].all())
```

If I were to do it with loops, I would do it like so -

```
num_simulations = 1000
num_success_before_pity_timer = 0

for _ in range(num_simulations):

    # this will loop between turn 1 to 199; if we don't get a pull by turn 199
    # will always succeed by turn 200
    for turn in range(1, 200):
        threshold = 0.995 if turn < 100 else 0.99
        if random.random() > threshold:
            num_success_before_pity_timer += 1
            break

successful_pull_percentage = num_success_before_pity_timer / num_simulations
print(successful_pull_percentage)
```

Comment: How do you do with loops? Can you edit your post, please?

Comment: @Corralien Sure, I've added my for-loop snippet, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found the error:

```
num_simulations = 1000
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(199, num_simulations))
df.loc[:100, :] = df.loc[:100, :] > 0.995  # True if > 0.995 (not <= 0.995)
df.loc[100:, :] = df.loc[100:, :] > 0.99   # True if > 0.99 (not <= 0.99)
sum(df.sum() > 0) / num_simulations  # change the counting method too
```

10 runs give me the following distribution:

`[0.776, 0.793, 0.792, 0.761, 0.793, 0.774, 0.792, 0.761, 0.753, 0.789]`

It's what you expected, isn't it?

**Edit**: a faster method without `pandas`:

```
N = 1000  # num_simulations
threshold = np.concatenate([np.full((99, N), 0.995), np.full((100, N), 0.99)])
values = np.random.random(size=(199, N))
np.sum(np.sum(values > threshold, axis=0) > 0) / N
```